# Is there any way to create a dynamic marker with a self-populating pie chart (within the marker) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, markers, dynamic, chart

I have to plot security incidents on a map, and while I have been having great success on QGIS with the general mapping, as well as using clusters to indicate more than one incident on the same location, I find that when I have to differentiate the type of incidents some would get lost if more than one occurred on the same coordinate position. On the previous software we used (that was not nearly as functional), we were able to indicate if multiple types of incidents occurred on the same location through a pie chart within the marker (see screenshot attached). How can I replicate this in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Did you try layer properties > Diagrams? See https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#diagrams-properties

Comment: @Babel, the diagrams are not adequate. I basically need the aesthetics of the "Point Cluster" Symbology, but with a Pie Chart instead of the font marker.